# Problems with Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit

Tags: 16.04, steam, crash

I am very new to Linux. (I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on this computer about an hour ago.) I am having difficulty installing Steam. It first said

> SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
>
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Then I tried doing other things online but they didn't work, and my computer crashed with something that looks like [this pink vertical line pattern](http://cdn.overclock.net/d/da/600x450px-LL-da083e37_Photo0778.jpeg). (This isn't my picture. I just found it on Google. It has some resemblance to what my crash screen looks like. It goes all checkerboard-like.)

Also, I think I should mention that I didn't use the .deb thing from the Steam website. I ran `sudo apt-get install steam` because it said I was forbidden from using the website or something.

I have 2.7GB RAM, an AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 220 Processor × 2, and for graphics I am using Gallium 0.4 on NV4C. (I don't have a GPU, so I don't know how I have graphics.)

Fun fact, my computer crashed while writing this because I had to open the "About this computer" tab to see my specs while I had Firefox open, so this is my second time writting this...

If you could help me, that would be awesome. I just want to play TF2 again. I know my computer probably won't be able to handle it anyways, but I want to get Steam and TF2 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

That version of steam must be *horrendously* outdated. Are you sure that you cannot access the steam download page? The download is [here](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb). After that, open up the Downloads folder and rename the file to "steam.deb" or something like that. Press `CTRL+ALT+T` and type `cd Downloads`

After that, type the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

Or whatever you named it.
Steam should be installed. If it says that steam is already installed, enter `sudo apt purge steam*` and it should uninstall the previous version of steam. If this does not fix your problem, there is probably something wrong with steam itself.

Comment: Hey zjjp, i tried clicking the link, but this is what i got: " Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at repo.steamstatic.com Port 80 "

Comment: Do you want me to upload it to GDrive for you?

Comment: Because that shouldn't happen

Comment: what is GDrive?

Comment: Google Drive is gdrive

Comment: Ah. Ok. Sure, if you could, that would be awesome.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-udAX9jXWT0c1BzWHdQWXB1LW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PsyKIngHD There is the link.

Comment: thank you. i am going to try to download it, then I'll try to do the next steps you told me to do. Thanks.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but this popped up: " dpkg: error processing archive steam.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam.deb "

Comment: I forgot to rename it sorry

Comment: This happened instead of it being installed: " Selecting previously unselected package steam.
(Reading database ... 181485 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack steam.deb ...
Unpacking steam (1.0.0.54) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam:
 steam depends on steam-launcher (>= 1.0.0.54); however:
  Package steam-launcher is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package steam (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam " and i already purged my existing steam.

Comment: Should i use GDebi Package Installer?

Comment: i am re installing Ubuntu and only using the information you have provided me with to install steam. i hope it works this time... I will be back in an hour or two with results...Thanks again... Bye.

Comment: So, after a while of searching on this website, I just downloaded windows 10. I hate Linux now because of this experience